# Can't ping router

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

When I first installed Fedora-38, I could reach the Internet, so the current lack of connectivity can't be drivers or cables. The NetworkManager was constantly attempting to connect wlp5s0, failing because it couldn't get the IP configuration (I'd love to know what caused that and how to fix it) and deactivating it. That was a problem because that I/F was the one tapping the router for DNS. In between, I'd have about 45-60 seconds of Internet connectivity.

So, ... I set up all three I/F with static IP, to eliminate DHCP issues. WiFi 5GHz on 192.168.0.125 (wlp5s0) and LAN I/F on 192.168.0.108 (enp8s0) and 192.168.0.109 (enp9s0).  Each I/F uses 192.168.0.1 as the gateway and DNS with 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as secondary DNSs.

The router sees 0.125 WiFi and 0.44 LAN, probably because 0.44 was the LAN's DHCP address before I reconfigured the LAN I/Fs with static IPs.  Another machine on the LAN can ping 0.44.

I don't understand why the router is hanging onto 0.44 and ignoring 0.108 and 0.109.  AND... I can't ping the router much less external IPs or domain names.

'ip r' shows all I/Fs as default via 0.1 and 'ip a' shows inet=0.108/24 0.109/24 and 0.125/24 respectively.

'resolvectl' shows:
Global as a stub current DNS=0.1
enp8s0's current DNS=0.1
enp9s0's current DNS=0.1
wlp5s0's current DNS=0.1

When I restart the NetworkManager with no DHCP negotiations, everything comes up fast, but the I/Fs might switch to DNS=8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 (they all have all three DNSs in their DNS lists).

I could use some suggestions on how to restore ping to router and Internet access.  [Please don't ask for giant chunks of info - I have to type it all in by hand.]

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's not a "DHCP issue" at all – the reason you can't ping stuff is the same reason you couldn't get a DHCP lease, i.e. the NICs became completely unable to either send and/or receive packets for some reason. Can you fire up Wireshark and check what shows up on each of the NICs? Can you test them independently (i.e. have one NIC disabled)?

Comment: enp8s0 had a bad cable, but after replacing that, I can see the whole LAN's traffic on enp8s0, enp9s0, and wlp5s0 (either 2.4GHz or 5GHz) one I/F active at a time. Lots of ARP "Who has 192.168.0.1" that aren't getting answered. I tried disabling the firewall and selinux, neither had any effect (so I have them running again).

Comment: Are the ARP requests coming from your machine? If they're coming from other hosts, you won't see answers as they go directly to that host.

Comment: From my machine.